# Replace no `contenteditable` não joga o ponteiro pro final

Tags: html, jquery

Estou tentando dar um replace no `contenteditable`, ele substitui mas não joga o ponteiro pro final, mantém sempre no inicio. Não conhecia o contenteditable ainda e não achei nada 'simples' que funcione.

O mesmo exemplo no elemento `input` funciona corretamente, mas no `contenteditable` acontece esse 'problema' - não sei se falta algo...

A ideia é substituir algumas palavras e manter o cursor no ponto de digitação.

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qrkpbte4/)**

```js
$(".elemento").on('input', function( e )
{
    content = $(this).html().replace(/foo/g, 'bar');
    $(this).html( content )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="elemento" contenteditable="true">
  foo bar
</div>
```

Comment: Se quiser delegar a complexidade em algo já feito, utilize a biblioteca [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy). Vale mencionar que ela tem compatibilidade para vários navegadores, incluindo o péssimo IE.

Answer (score 0):

Para isso você pode usar o objeto `Range` e posicioná-lo onde deseja.
Referência https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Range

Aqui um exemplo:

```js
$('#botao').click(function () {
    var div = $("#texto");
    var content = $(div).html();
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    // posição do texto
    var pos = content.indexOf("foo");
    // substitiu
    content = content.replace(/foo/g, 'bar');
    $(div).html(content);
    // cria um range, selecionando o primeiro conteúdo do div, na posição do texto "foo". 
    range.setStart(texto.childNodes[0], pos);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    // posiciona no range
    sel.addRange(range);
    div.focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="texto" contenteditable="true">
  Isso é um teste com foo no texto
</div>

<button id="botao">Posicionar</button>
```